# When to use equality operator over binding operator

Tags: regex, perl, equality

recently I have become friendly with regular expressions and used them to over come a number of tasks very efficiently. As with most perl TIMTOWTDI has clouded my judgement. There are times I can use equality operator or binding operator. However are there times where it is more appropriate to use one over the other?

Firstly the simplified case

```
my $name = 'Chris';
if ($name eq 'Chris') { print 'What a great name!'; }
if ($name =~/^Chris$/) { print 'Yip sure is a great name; }
```

So in this case this is the most simplified, where using the equality is less typing, however in this simplified example is there any benefit to one or the other.

In a slightly more complex example

```
my $name = 'Christopher';
if ($name eq 'Chris' || $name eq 'Christopher') { print 'What a great name!'; }
if ($name =~ /^Chris(?:topher)?$/) { print 'Yip sure is a great name; }
```

here the binding operator is less typing. However I am not sure of the benefit either may hold over the other.

So is the general rule if you are matching an entire string with a fixed value to use equality operator and if your matching a string with a pattern for example any 5 digits string `/\d{5}/` then use binding operator.

Is it inappropriate to use binding operator in the above examples. I appreciate that these examples are just made up and may not reflect a real life problem. However they were the ones i thought of to try to explain my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> however in this simplified example is there any benefit to one or the other.

Well, they're not equivalent. `/^Chris$/` matches `Chris` and `Chris` followed by a newline.

If you had used an equivalent pattern (`/^Chris\z/`), the difference would have been performance. A single string comparison will be faster than a regex match. It's also clearer.

For more complicated comparisons, you generally want to go with what's simpler, clearer, and more maintainable. Address performance (by using profile and running benchmarks) when it becomes an issue.

Comment: Maintainability is the key concern here, IMO. In this particular case I'd go with the `eq` option in both cases since it conveys the intent of the developer better. While I appreciate the academic discussion, there's a real risk of premature optimization here. @ikegami has it spot-on: optimize only when you're witnessing an issue. Wise people run stress-tests relatively early in development, though.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect slightly (if at all) better performance from the `eq` operator because the regular expression might require a compilation phase as well as analysis before coming up with its determination.

So in the case:

```
if ($name eq 'Chris') { print 'What a great name!'; }
if ($name =~/^Chris$/) { print 'Yip sure is a great name; }
```

... I would expect the first statement to be fastest.

In the second example, however, you have to consider the summed times of the failed cases where you've provided a logical OR:

```
if ($name eq 'Chris' || $name eq 'Christopher') { print 'What a great name!'; }
if ($name =~ /^Chris(?:topher)?$/) { print 'Yip sure is a great name; }
```

... here things are less cut and dried. Sure, `eq` may be faster, but are two `eq`s faster than a regular expression which doesn't have to backtrack (in this example)? I can't be so sure.

Usually you won't have to consider the performance benefits. So you can't argue one is "better" than the other - I'd usually encourage code clarity in this situation. But it's important to realise that `eq` is very unforgiving while regular expressions are very flexible - allowing for case-insensitive searches, anchoring to just the beginning, etc. When you *do* hit some code in which comparison speed is critical then ultimately you'll want to benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

The power of regular expressions is realized in its variability.
When you give a regex engine a template, you "suggest" match outcomes to the engine.
Inernally, its the same C "strncmp()" and such as you would do as in Perl, ie: $str eq "asdf", both are templates.

However, you cannot describe variablilty very well with just a language, thats why regular expression engines exist.

There is an overhead to "eterring" the engine, ie: reset variables, state tracking etc..
But after that, the engine will outperform any combination of language constructs you can
concieve of. Not by a little, but by a huge, huge percentage.

Comment: Poppycock. If you created a trie of all the possible matching string, it'll kick the regex engine's butt. People use regex engine because it's not usually feasible to do that. (Too many strings, or too much hassle to maintain a computed trie.)